# Список с разделителем

Tags: android

На рисунке ниже есть список. У него элементы разделены тонкой серой линией, но она прерывается слева где кружочек. Как сделать такую же разметку для списка?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать [DividerItemDecoration](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/DividerItemDecoration.html). Пример:

```
  mDividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(), mLayoutManager.getOrientation());
  mDividerItemDecoration.setDrawable(getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.line_divider));
  recyclerView.addItemDecoration(mDividerItemDecoration);
```

Где `line_divider.xml`:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
    <size
        android:width="1dp"
        android:height="1dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/primary" />
</shape>
```

Измените `line_divider.xml` для достижения своих задач.